# Can I denote a glyph as being two chars (NA) in a box file in Tesseract 3.05

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

I am using tesseract 3.05 for reasons beyond my control. I am using source files to train the engine to detect this unique font. As I have a vast amount of samples, I am simply using the samples themselves as the training images rather than segment them into a font training image as this should give it more variation and training with the specific spacing issues this font has.

My question when generating the box files, as some letters are touching at corners (i.e . no clear break between glyphs), it will detect them as one glyph instead of two separate glyphs. An example it sometimes struggles with NA as the front serif of the A has bled into serif of the N. The image pre-processing I have applied has improved it by leaps and bounds but there are still some that I cannot correct on the image enough.

My question is this: can I simply denote the glyph as being NA in the box file?
If I cannot what would be the simplest solution? Introducing another glyph box seems like it wouldn't be a good idea but the only other solution I can see is to manually edit the image to make the separation of glyphs more obvious. This is itself anthi-thetical however as this is the kind of problem the font will have in the future that I am trying to OCR.

Thank you in advance but the documentation isn't specific on if I can correct a box glyph to being two characters instead of just one (or I just haven't found a relevant section where they explain this).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do not know much about Tesseract so unfortunately, I cannot help very much to find an answer. But I was wondering, to make it easier to find for others in the future, whether it would make sense to phrase the title of your question more directly as something like `Is it possible to set a box glyph to being two characters in Tesseract 3.05` or `Can I denote the glyph as being NA in the box file in Tesseract 3.05`? Just an idea.

Comment: Thank you @CEGRD, I was using it more as a article stlye posting forum but I see now (after looking around the site) it is literally meant to be a forum with each thread being a question.

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the documentation, I managed to find a lone paragraph that wasn't appearing in my website scraping:

"If you didn't successfully space out the characters on the training image, some may have been joined into a single box. In this case, you can either remake the images with better spacing and start again, or if the pair is common, put both characters at the start of the line, leaving the bounding box to represent them both. (As of 3.00, there is a limit of 24 bytes for the description of a "character". This will allow you between 6 and 24 unicodes to describe the character, depending on where your codes sit in the unicode set. If anyone hits this limit, please file an issue describing your situation.)"

Thus you can do what I ask: represent a glyph with two or more characters in a box file for Tesseract.